# Main Network vs Private Network: pro and cons

Tags: private-blockchain

i need to understand the difference between Main Network and Private Network.

Private network is only for test or it can be used for a real project?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

so it depends, if you want to use the public ethereum blockchain (accessible by anybody) the main network is where you deploy production applications. a private network means you create one or many ethereum nodes and only and people you give permission to have access to those nodes, you could use that for testing for example or in a company setting where you have private data. 
there are other public networks that are for testing only such as Ropsten, Rinkeby and Kovan

Comment: Thank you Adil for your response!
So I cannot use Main Network for Private data because all data are public. But I think that the power of blockchain is the distributed data in many computer. So if I create a private blockchain, all data is distributed in few computer. In your opinion my consideration is right or wrong?

Comment: yes I think you are right. there are ways to store private data on the public blockchain though, for example you could encrypt it and store it there

Comment: @este.lombardo, please mark the answer as the correct one if it indeed answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is a fundamental issue when using a private Ethereum network for anything else than test and experimentation:

Depending on the number of nodes you intend to deploy, you will have to reduce the complexity of the POW consensus significantly. It means that the security and integrity of your private blockchain will not rely anymore on the blockchain itself but on external protections to prevent fraudulent nodes to join your network. Then why use Ethereum at all ?

Answer (score 0):

**Mainnet**

- security of thousands of nodes agreeing on the set of state
- everything is public
- permissionless; anyone can join the network
- transactions cost money

**Private network**

- basically the same as a distributed database
- can have private data (since the chain is non-public)
- can be permissioned-based
- transactions can be free